# Iteratively combine ordered sets without repetitions

Tags: combinatorics

I have arbitrary number of ordered sets of arbitrary length each, I will pick two for better explanation:
$A = \{A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3} ... A_{n}\}$
$B = \{B_{1}, B_{2}, B_{3} ... B_{m}\}$
I need to collect $k$ number from working combinations of these sets and want to do it iteratively starting from smaller indexes, since they are more preferred, but have smaller chance to work. So in first iteration combine entities with index 1:
$(A_{1}, B_{1})$
And then check how many combinations will meet some criteria, if number of working combinations is less than $k$ I want to explore indexes 1 and 2, but without repetitions from previous iteration:
$(A_{1}, B_{2})$
$(A_{2}, B_{1})$
$(A_{2}, B_{2})$
And repeat that process until I will find $k$ number of combinations or there are no more combinations to check.
Is there any way to achieve this without storing previous combinations to avoid repetitions?
Any help is appreciated, may be any papers I can read or some buzzwords I can use for googling.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I was would also be interested if there is a method or a keyword that I could read more about this.